# Scraping using scrapy only able to get the first record

Tags: python, scrapy

Newbie here trying to scrape https://www.worldometers.info/coronavirus/countries-where-coronavirus-has-spread/

This is the function I've wrote. Is it a problem with the xpath?

```
def parse(self, response):

    for row in response.xpath("//table[@id='table3']"):
        name = row.xpath(".//tr//td[1]//text()").get()
        yield {
            'name': name
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

`pandas` can scrape tables quickly:

```
import pandas as pd
import requests

url = 'https://www.worldometers.info/coronavirus/countries-where-coronavirus-has-spread/'

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36'}

r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

df = pd.read_html(r.text)
```

The table can be found in `df[0]`. `df[0].head()`:

|  | Country | Cases | Deaths | Region |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | United States | 34592377 | 621293 | North America |
| 1 | India | 30585229 | 402758 | Asia |
| 2 | Brazil | 18769808 | 524475 | South America |
| 3 | France | 5786203 | 111161 | Europe |
| 4 | Russia | 5635294 | 138579 | Europe |

You can save it with `df[0].to_csv('filename.csv')`.

Comment: Thanks thats a neat way to do it. Whats the problem with my scrapy program though? Its selecting all the items in the browser but its not scrapping

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind I got it to work I. Just needed to turn JavaScript off when selecting the the xpath